# non-standard Storyboard view controller initialization (not -initWithCoder:)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib, initwithcoder

Is there a way to use init methods other than `-initWithCoder:` for Storyboard view controllers? I already know that you can set properties on VCs inside `-prepareForSegue:`.

Comment: do some research before posting questions, please

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `-initWithNibName:` to load a nib file for the view.
     You need to follow these steps:

1. First you define the class for the view Controller created .
2. Then delete the view attribute from that controller in the storyboard
3. Then you can use nib file to initialize the class .

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't not provide a solution for the OP issue, as he explicitly mentioned *for Storyboard view controllers*, anyway he'll be the judge of it.